# Collecting FAA data using the SWIM jumpstart utility

Tags: bash

I am collecting FAA data for a project. I have created a data subscription at https://accounts.swim.faa.gov/ and am using their "jumpstart" utility to start data collection. The issue is that I am collecting the data on a Google VM and the jumpstart seems to need to be manually started. I ssh to the vm, start the utility using the given command string and when my session times out, the collection utility stops.

The utility seems to want to be started in the directory where it lives. I created the following script and start it @reboot in crontab:

```
cd /home/helotbc/faa
./bin/run -Dconfig.file=download.config
```

I see the utility running in HTOP (graphic) [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ErQ6h.png), but there is no data being generated in the /log directory. The question is, how do I launch the utility and collect data in a way that it will not be tied to my ssh session? Thanks.

Comment: I have no experience with Google VM and jumpstart, but you can try `nohup ./bin/run -Dconfig.file=download.config >>/log/run_log.$(date +\%Y\%m\%d).txt 2>&1) &` . Cant be sure if your system will honor `nohup` OR the `&` (run in the background), but it shouldn't take long to find out. I've added a separate log so you will have any output/error messages captured to a file that you can inspect.